# How to drop a enqueued message in activemq?

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue

Im working on a project when the producer is sending messages at a fast rate, and the broker should enqueue all of them, but drop the oldest ones when memory (or other, like max. messages number) limit is reached. I've tried messing with a `constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy` parameter but it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to achieve it by editing the broker section in the **activemq.xml** file?

```
<destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
    <policyEntry queue="*.prioritized" prioritizedMessages="true" useCache="false" expireMessagesPeriod="0" queuePrefetch="1" memoryLimit="10mb" producerFlowControl="true">
        <pendingQueuePolicy>
        <vmQueueCursor/>
        </pendingQueuePolicy>
        </policyEntry>
    <policyEntry queue="TestNotifications" expireMessagesPeriod="10" memoryLimit="50mb" producerFlowControl="true">
        <pendingQueuePolicy>
        <vmQueueCursor/>
        </pendingQueuePolicy>
        </policyEntry>
    <policyEntry queue=">" expireMessagesPeriod="0" memoryLimit="50mb" producerFlowControl="true">
        <pendingQueuePolicy>
        <vmQueueCursor/>
        </pendingQueuePolicy>
        <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="10"/>
        </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
        </policyEntry>

    <policyEntry topic=">" >
              <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="100"/>
              </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
```

Answer (score 1):

PendingMessageLimitStrategy types are only applicable to Topics, it would have no affect on a Queue.  Queue messages are stored in memory and paged to disk (based on cursor configuration) or the store when the limits are reached.  If you want messages to be discarded then you need to set a TTL on the message and allow the broker to periodically discard them as they expire.

Comment: I've set a TTL on my messages, however they're still not being discarded.  How do I allow the broker to discard them? I've tried `<sharedDeadLetterStrategy processExpired="false" />`. Im using a 5.13.2 version.

Comment: I've already changed it to 3000 and it doesn't help, however as far as I understand it shouldn't matter since I'm testing it on the "TestNotifications" queue.